# How to use the grep result in command line?

Tags: bash, grep

When I use `grep` to find some text which I need, it will display lines containing a match to the given pattern.

For example,

```
# grep -r ".*Linux" *
path0/output.txt:I hope you enjoyed working on Linux.
path1/output1.txt:Welcome to Linux.
path2/output2.txt:I hope you will have fun with Linux.
```

then, I want to edit the file `path2/output2.txt`, hence, I type `vim path2/output2.txt`.

But, I don't think it is an effective way.

How can I copy the path after `grep`?

Comment: That's on the top of wishlists by the way; tab completion for things used in the last command: i.e. the files outputed by grep in the last command, or the files used in the last command.

Comment: Please keep feature requests to the upstream project. Also contact the vendor for your support options first. No need to drive attention away from the original project(s).

Comment: @Erik Johansson: Isn't there a bash command to shedule for the next commands tabbing?

Answer (score 6):

```
vim `grep -r ".*Linux" * | cut -f1 -d":"`
```

backticks are for command substitution. `|` is for piping output of grep to cut. `-d":"` says cut based on delimited `:`. `-f1` says the first field after cutting.

Comment: Just a note: backtics are deprecated. `$(command)` should be used instead..

Answer (score 6):

These are **safe ways** to find all files with Linux (lower and upper case).

```
xargs -a <(grep -rlZi Linux *) -0 vim
grep -rlZi Linux *| xargs -0 sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim
grep -rlZi Linux *| xargs -0 vim # you need to run reset after this command
```

There are differences between GNU xargs and BSD xargs so might not work on MacOSX.

- -Z and -0 options are for NULL delimited filenames
- -l for outputting the filenames of the files that match.
- -i match lower and uppcase.
- -o on bsd xargs  will do the same as the "sh -c" part

Comment: Using `vim` with `xargs` may result in the warning, `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`, and a messed up terminal.

Comment: True, bsd xargs has a -o options, I've supplied a fix from GNU xargs man page above.

Answer (score 3):

You can nest your `grep` command in as an argument to `vim ...`. The `grep` command will produce the list of files all as a single argument to `vim`, when it get's expanded. Also you can simplify your search criteria to just `' Linux'` for the examples you've given, it's not necessary to include the `.*` wildcard.

#### List of files

This command will generate the list of files for `vim`.

```
$ grep -lr ' Linux' *
path0/output.txt
path1/output1.txt
path2/output2.txt
```

You can nest this inside of a command substitution block (`$(..)`), like so:

```
$(grep -lr ' Linux' *)
```

You can use `echo` to see what this list will end up looking on the command line when passed to `vim`:

```
$ echo $(grep -lr ' Linux' *)
path0/output.txt path1/output1.txt path2/output2.txt
```

#### Putting it all together

```
$ vim $(grep -lr ' Linux' *)
3 files to edit
...
```

With this approach you just need to be careful if your list of files is going to be extremely long. But in general this is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Good editors let you run grep inside.

In Vim, run `:grep -r ".*Linux" .`

In Emacs, run `M-x grep` and type `".*Linux" -r .`